# com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Characters are not supported, please strings

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to Firebase. I am trying to save POJO that sent from Android to Realtime Database.

I have a POJO like this:

```
@IgnoreExtraProperties
public class Member implements Parcelable{

public String name;

public Member() {}

public Member(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

/**=================== */
/** Parcelable section */
/**=================== */

public static final Parcelable.Creator CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator() {
    public Member createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new Member(in);
    }

    public Member[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Member[size];
    }
};

public Member(Parcel in){
    this.name = in.readString();
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeString(this.name);
}
}
```

And activity like this:

```
package com.example.view;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

import com.example.R;
import com.example.model.Member;

public class TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

DatabaseReference myRef;

Button button;
TextView text;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
    myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_test);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_test);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            sendDataToFirebase();
        }
    });
}

private void sendDataToFirebase() {
    String key = myRef.push().getKey();
    Member member = new Member("John");
    myRef.child("Member").child("john").child(key).setValue(member);
}
}
```

Then appear this error after I clicked the button:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example, PID: 16332
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Characters are not supported, please strings
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zg.zzao(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zg.zzar(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zh.zzas(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zg.zzao(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zg.zzan(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.zza(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.setValue(Unknown Source)
    at com.example.view.TestActivity.sendDataToFirebase(TestActivity.java:43)
    at com.example.view.TestActivity.access$000(TestActivity.java:15)
    at com.example.view.TestActivity$1.onClick(TestActivity.java:35)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5714)
    at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10926)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22594)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

I can't find out what's wrong with my code. I have followed tutorial from [Firebase official website](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write) and others tutorial. I followed them carefully and I've tried many times. I have googling for hours, but no hope.

Hope will get some solution or advice from this community.
Many thanks :)

Comment: `TestActivity.java:56`... What's at that line?

Comment: Sorry my bad, I displayed wrong error code. I have edited it. @cricket_007

Comment: Again, what's at that line?

Comment: It refer to code `myRef.child("Member").child("john").child(key).setValue(member);`. I just know that

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue when i was initializing an element of object in its constructor without passing the value for it. Like :

```
public class ChatMessage {
private String messageText;
private String messageUser;
private String messageTime;
private String photoURL;

dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aa");

public ChatMessage() {
}

public ChatMessage(String messageText, String messageUser, String photoURL) {
    this.messageText = messageText;
    this.messageUser = messageUser;
    this.photoURL = photoURL;
    **this.messageTime = dateFormat.format(new Date()).toString();**
}


public String getMessageText() {
    return messageText;
}

public void setMessageText(String messageText) {
    this.messageText = messageText;
}

public String getMessageUser() {
    return messageUser;
}

public void setMessageUser(String messageUser) {
    this.messageUser = messageUser;
}

public String getMessageTime() {
    return messageTime;
}

public void setMessageTime(String messageTime) {
    this.messageTime = messageTime;
}

public String getPhotoURL() {
    return photoURL;
}

public void setPhotoURL(String photoURL) {
    this.photoURL = photoURL;
}
```

}

Then i changed it to :

```
    public class ChatMessage {
private String messageText;
private String messageUser;
private String messageTime;
private String photoURL;


public ChatMessage() {
}

public ChatMessage(String messageText, String messageUser, String photoURL, String messageTime) {
    this.messageText = messageText;
    this.messageUser = messageUser;
    this.photoURL = photoURL;
    this.messageTime = messageTime;
}


public String getMessageText() {
    return messageText;
}

public void setMessageText(String messageText) {
    this.messageText = messageText;
}

public String getMessageUser() {
    return messageUser;
}

public void setMessageUser(String messageUser) {
    this.messageUser = messageUser;
}

public String getMessageTime() {
    return messageTime;
}

public void setMessageTime(String messageTime) {
    this.messageTime = messageTime;
}

public String getPhotoURL() {
    return photoURL;
}

public void setPhotoURL(String photoURL) {
    this.photoURL = photoURL;
}
}
```

Using below lines in MainActivity to push POJO in FireBaseDataBase:

```
     ChatMessage msg = new 
     ChatMessage(s,mUserName,null,dateFormat.format(new Date()).toString());
     mMessagesDatabaseReference.push().setValue(msg);
```

And this works for me now with firebase database. Hope this helps you too.

[firebase-database](/questions/tagged/firebase-database) [pojo](/questions/tagged/pojo)